# Show first entry by timestamp of each event group

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

we collect custom events in application insights for each message a user sends to a chatbot. The event is called `user_message`. 
We use a custom dimension field `customDimensions.conversationid` to know which message is related to which conversation.

I want to see the first message of each conversation so basically the "oldest" timestamp of each event based on the conversation id.

I tried to work with arg_max but I didn't figure out how it works.

```
customEvents
| extend itemType = iif(itemType == 'customEvent',itemType,"")
| where (itemType == 'customEvent')
| where name == 'User_Message'
```

i was able to show all user messages ordert by the conversationID however it shows me multiple lines and i only need the first message by conversation.

Datamodel:

```
timestamp [UTC] 2019-04-05T13:24:10.359Z
name User_Message
itemType customEvent
    customDimensions
    confidence N/A 
    conversationId BNu0SqC5RfA1S0lZmdxxxxx
    intent N/A
    userMessage user text
operation_Name POST /api/messages
operation_Id xxxxxxxa5d422eadebfebb2
operation_ParentId xxxxx545a5d422eadebfebb2.99811380_13.f033f887_
application_Version 1.0.0
client_Type PC
client_OS Windows_NT 10.0.14393
client_IP 0.0.0.0
client_City Amsterdam
client_StateOrProvince North Holland
client_CountryOrRegion Netherlands
cloud_RoleName Web
cloud_RoleInstance XXXXXXXFF74D594
appId ccccccc-8b24-41bb-a02a-1cb101da84e5
appName bot-XXXXX
iKey XXXXXX
sdkVersion node:XX
itemId XXXXXXXX-57a6-11e9-a5a7-ebc91e7cf64e
itemCount 1
```

SOLUION

```
customEvents
| extend itemType = iif(itemType == 'customEvent',itemType,"")
| where (itemType == 'customEvent')
| where (name=='User_Message')
| summarize list=makeset(customDimensions.userMessage) by 
tostring(customDimensions.conversationId)
| mv-expand firstMessage=list[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

```
customEvents 
| where name == "User_Message"
| summarize timestamp=min(timestamp) by myconid=tostring(customDimensions.[conversationID])
| join kind= inner (
   customEvents
   | where name == "User_Message"
   | extend myconid = tostring(customDimensions.[conversationID])
) on myconid,timestamp
```

You can use inner join to do that.

I don't have your data, so in your case, the code looks like below(maybe you need to make a little changes):

```
customEvents
| summarize timestamp=min(timestamp) by conversationID 
| join kind= inner (
   customEvents
) on conversationID,timestamp
| project-away conversationID1,timestamp1
```

Please let me know if you have more issues.

Comment: thank you for the answer but unfortunatelly it does not work.

Comment: i solced the issue, the solution is in the entry post. Thank you ivan yang

Comment: You're welcome. I figure out an answer also, it works at my side. if it's ok, do you mind accept it as an answer. Thanks.